# Node.js Unix socket not echoing

Tags: node.js, bash, sockets, unix

I am trying to create a file which I can `cat` or `echo` strings to and receive strings back as output. If I understand correctly I can do this with a Unix socket.

I've tried to write a server but I can't seem to get it to recognize my input:

```
'use strict';

var net = require('net'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    socketAddress = '/tmp/test-socket',
    server;

server = net.createServer(function (client) {
    var whole = '';
    client.on('data', function (data) {
        whole += data;
    });
    client.on('end', function () {
        client.write(whole);
    });
});

fs.unlink(socketAddress, function (error) {
    if (error && error.code !== 'ENOENT') {
        throw error;
    }
    server.listen(socketAddress, function () {
        console.log('Socket listening at ' + socketAddress);
    });
});
```

I try to do `echo 'Hello World!' | /tmp/test-socket` and I get `bash: /tmp/test-socket: No such device or address`. But `ls -l /tmp` yields:

`srwxr-xr-x 1 jackson jackson    0 Jun  1 01:10 test-socket`

Please advise on how I can get this socket to echo the strings I write to it.

Answer (score 1):

`test-socket` is not a program. The pipe operator (`|`) tries to execute the  next argument (in this case `test-socket`) as a program or script and pass the output to its stdin.

Since sockets (named pipes) are essentially files, you need to use the `>` or `>>` operator:

```
echo 'Hello World!' > /tmp/test-socke
```

This of course assumes that your node code is working.

Comment: Sure. However, running `echo 'Hello World!' > /tmp/test-socket` still results in `bash: /tmp/test-socket: No such device or address`. (I expect to see "Hello World!" printed out.)

Comment: Did you use mknod or mkfifo to create the test-socket file?

Comment: I used the program in the OP.

Comment: Can you try creating the file using mkfifo? Then in the program don't unlink the file but just start listening to it. The file creation part of the library may be buggy.

Comment: If use `rm /tmp/test-socket && mkfifo /tmp/test-socket` and try to run my program I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`.

Answer (score 1):

The `/tmp/test-socket` is not a file. It's a socket file. That's what the leading s means in `srwxr-xr-x`. Bash's redirection like `>` does not support socket files. With [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat) (a 'bidirectional data relay between two data channels') you can connect to the unix domain socket like this:

```
echo 'Hello World!' | socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/test-socke -
```